# How to stop Azure PostgreSQL replication using powershell with Azure Function

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I am new to Azure Power shell and Azure functions.

I have requirement where I have to execute Powershell command to stop PostgreSQL replication

I created the Azure function app with default options and created the function. Inside the function I updated with `Get-AzSubscription`.  I am getting error for all azure commands.

```
"Get-AzResource/Get-AzSubscription/Get-AzModule" is not recognized as a name of cmdlet or function or Scrip file or executable program
```

but I am able to execute the "Get-Date" and get required results

Please suggest how to fixes to this issue
Thanks in advance
Ramabadran

Answer (score 0):

> "Get-AzResource/Get-AzSubscription/Get-AzModule" is not recognized as a name of cmdlet or function or Scrip file or executable program

To run the PowerShell cmdlets on Azure PowerShell Runtime Stack Function App/Project, you need to uncomment the `Az module` in  `requirements.psd1`  with the Az module version i.e.,  [compatible](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az/4.1.0)  with PowerShell Version you're using the Function App:

**`requirements.psd1`**:

```
@{
'Az' = '8.*'
}
```

**`run.ps1`**:

```
using  namespace  System.Net

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
Write-Host  "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."
  
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant '<Azure-tenant-id>' -SubscriptionId '<Azure-Subscription-Id>' 
$SubscriptionInfo = Get-AzSubscription -TenantId "<Azure-tenant-id>"
Write-Host  $SubscriptionInfo

$body = "Hello Jahnavi, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
  
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
Body = $body
})
```

**Result**:  [image]

**Note**: Also, Install the Azure modules in the Function app workspace of the VS Code Terminal using these cmdlets  `Install-Module Az`,  `Import-Module Az`.